# NSMutableArray out of bounds only when populated with another array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, nsmutablearray

So I have a UItableView that auto populates cells based upon user input. I have a master array of Colors names called arrColors, and a 'temp' array called arrAutoCorrect, that is populated when the user types.

Both arrays are NSMutableArrays.

If the user clears out all the text, the temp array should be fully loaded from all the colors.
There are 21 colors (strings) in the colors array.

I get an index out of bounds 17 ( 0 - 16 ) error.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 17 beyond bounds [0 .. 16]'
```

It's driving me crazy.

Where is this 17 coming from? Again the error only presents it self when the user has cleared all the contents of the textbox.

I have NSLogged just about everything I can, and I can't find what is calling this 17 in range.

**My code**

```
- (void)searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:(NSString *)substring :(NSMutableArray*) passedArray {

    [self.arrAutoComplete removeAllObjects];

    if ([substring length] == 0 ) {
        //add all items
        int count = 0;
        for (NSString* c in passedArray) {
            NSLog(@"Count: %i", count);
            [self.arrAutoComplete addObject:c];
            count++;
        }

    } else {
        //Narrow down
        for(NSString *curString in passedArray) {
            NSRange substringRange = [curString rangeOfString:substring options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            NSLog(@"my range is %@", NSStringFromRange(substringRange));
            if (substringRange.location == 0) {
                [self.arrAutoComplete addObject:curString];
            }
        }

    }
    [self.autocompleteTableView reloadData];
}



#pragma mark - TABLE VIEW DELEGATES

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

        // Return the number of sections.
        //NSLog(@"Number of sections to call for autocomplete table is: 1");
        return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


        // NSLog(@"Number of rows in section for autocomplete is: %lu", (long)[self.arrAutoComplete count]);
        return [self.arrAutoComplete count];



}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    //NSLog(@"Default cell delegate called");
    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
    // NSLog(@"Section: %lu", (unsigned long)section);

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSLog(@"Row : %lu", (unsigned long)row);


        //NSLog(@"Cell for autocomplete called");

        static NSString *AutoCompleteRowIdentifier = @"AutoCompleteRowIdentifier";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            //NSLog(@"Cell for autocomplete was nil, createing new");
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];
        }

        //NSLog(@"Indes path row: %lu", indexPath.row);
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.arrColors objectAtIndex:row];
        //NSLog(@"Cell for autocomplete text should be: %@",[self.arrColors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] );



    return cell;
}
```

My Crash log

```
2015-02-04 17:47:46.512 App[4033:1312614] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 17 beyond bounds [0 .. 16]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001037c9f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010310bbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001036c201e -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 190
    3   UIKit                               0x0000000104193856 -[UITableViewDataSource tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:] + 109
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000103ec726b __66-[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:]_block_invoke + 302
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000103ec68fe -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 4125
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000103eca098 -[UITableViewRowData numberOfRows] + 97
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000103d328fc -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] + 133
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000103d3203d -[UITableView reloadData] + 1316
```

**Additional information:**
If I comment out the adding of all the colors `searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring` where the substring length is 0, then app doesn't crash.

**NSLOG STATMENTS**

```
2015-02-04 17:54:19.155 Tops[4065:1359488] Number of sections to call for autocomplete table is: 1
2015-02-04 17:54:19.155 Tops[4065:1359488] Number of rows in section for autocomplete is: 3
2015-02-04 17:54:19.156 Tops[4065:1359488] Default cell delegate called
2015-02-04 17:54:19.156 Tops[4065:1359488] Section: 0
2015-02-04 17:54:19.156 Tops[4065:1359488] Row : 0
2015-02-04 17:54:19.157 Tops[4065:1359488] Default cell delegate called
2015-02-04 17:54:19.157 Tops[4065:1359488] Section: 0
2015-02-04 17:54:19.157 Tops[4065:1359488] Row : 1
2015-02-04 17:54:19.158 Tops[4065:1359488] Default cell delegate called
2015-02-04 17:54:19.158 Tops[4065:1359488] Section: 0
2015-02-04 17:54:19.158 Tops[4065:1359488] Row : 2
2015-02-04 17:54:19.612 Tops[4065:1359488] Substring: 
2015-02-04 17:54:19.612 Tops[4065:1359488] Count: 0
2015-02-04 17:54:19.612 Tops[4065:1359488] Count: 1
//Removed for brevity
2015-02-04 17:54:19.617 Tops[4065:1359488] Count: 19
2015-02-04 17:54:19.617 Tops[4065:1359488] Count: 20
2015-02-04 17:54:19.617 Tops[4065:1359488] Number of sections to call for autocomplete table is: 1
2015-02-04 17:54:19.618 Tops[4065:1359488] Number of rows in section for autocomplete is: 21
2015-02-04 17:54:19.622 Tops[4065:1359488] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 17 beyond bounds [0 .. 16]'
```

**UPDATE RESOLVED**

I was missing the method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 60.0f;//some random number
}
```

Be sure to read your documentation, kiddies.

Comment: Can you post the output from the `NSLog`s?  The exception says there are 17 objects in the array, and you are trying to access the 18th (index 17, since arrays start at 0).  Which line is the crash on?

Comment: There are 21 objects in the passedArray for the searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring method. The passed in array is the arrColors

Comment: Which line does it crash on?

Comment: I added an excerpt of my crash log.

Comment: Can you post any other output you got, even your `NSLog` statements?

Comment: Can you post your `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and set an Exception Breakpoint and then tell us at which line it is crashing at.

Comment: I do not have a 'tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:' method

Comment: Holy F @RoboticCat I have spent 3 hours on this POS method and that was it.

Comment: Can you self-answer your question so it doesn't show up as Unanswered?

Comment: If you are currently using a manual row height, I would think of changing to a cell height defined by the constraints in your `UITableViewCell`. It's basically needed to support Dynamic Type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 60.0f;//some random number
}
```

Even though I was using a Static Cell, (which didn't require the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` ), the dynamic table did.